# Child process becomes Defunct after fork and exec

Tags: c++, linux, fork, exec

I am learning fork and exec and creating multiple child processes using fork and execlp and all I do in the child process is let it sleep. Basically I just want all my child to be alive. But as soon as i start my monitor.cpp which creates processes all of the child exit immediately and they do defunct!

Monitor which forks multiple children

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 for(size_t i=0; i<std::stoi(argv[1]) ; ++i)
 {
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
  {
    execlp("child", "child", std::string(std::to_string(i)).c_str(), (char *)0);
    std::cout << "child exiting " << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  else if(pid > 0)
  {
   std::cout <<"child started with " << pid << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
   std::cout << "fork failed" << std::endl;
  }
 }

 while(true)
 {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100000));
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Child Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << " child started with id " << argv[1] << std::endl;

  std::cout <<"child sleeping " << argv[1] << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1000));

  std::cout << "child exiting " << argv[1] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> child started with 1834
> child started with 1835
> child exiting 
> child started with 1836
> child exiting 
> child started with 1837
> child started with 1838
> child started with 1839
> child exiting 
> child started with 1840
> child started with 1841
> child exiting 
> child started with 1842
> child started with 1843
> child exiting 
> child exiting 
> child exiting 
> child exiting 
> child exiting 
> child exiting
> ```

ps -ef shows all of my child processes as Defunct even though my parent is still alive.

Can you please explain what am I missing?

Comment: `execlp` failed.  If `execlp` returns, it will return `-1`, and you need to check `errno` to figure out what the error was.  My guess is that it can't find the 'child' binary.  Is it in a directory in your PATH?

Comment: If `execlp` succeeds, it does not return – there is nothing there for it to return to.

Answer (score 2):

From the 'execlp' man page:

> The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Since `"child exiting"` is being printed in two places, it's not obvious if it's exiting. You need to check it's return value and  `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reap the child-process as they exit. This is done using `wait` or `waitpid` calls.

Until the parent has done this, they will be visible as defunc / zombie processes. (init, process 1, is responsible for reaping all process that do not have a parent after they exit)